# Check for Scrabble double letter bonus

Tags: typescript, cyclomatic-complexity

This function checks if the cell of a Scrabble board is a double letter bonus. It has a 23 cyclomatic complexity, which is higher than the threshold of 20. I don't know how to do it another way, I think that this is the only way to do it. Here is my function :

```
checkDoubleLetterCell(row: number, column: number): boolean
{
if((row === middle- 1 || row === middle + 1)
&& (column === middle - 1 || column === middle + 1)
|| (row === 0 || row == SCRABBLE_SIZE - 1 || row === middle) 
&& (column === middle + Math.round(middle/2) || column === middle - Math.round(middle/2))
|| (column === 0 || column === SCRABBLE_SIZE - 1 || column === middle)
&& (row === middle + Math.round(middle/2) || row === middle - Math.round(middle/2))
|| (column === middle + 1 || column === middle - 1)
&& (row === middle + Math.round(middle/2) + 1 || row === middle - Math.round(middle/2) - 1)
|| (row === middle + 1 || row === middle - 1)
&& (column === middle + Math.round(middle/2) + 1 || column === middle - Math.round(middle/2) - 1))
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe break it into smaller functions?

Answer (score 3):

So, I am going to answer you javascript question using python code because I think the concepts are identical and I was too lazy to make sure my javascript syntax was right.

A couple of ways to simplify your expression include:

**Use a lookup table:**

I find this implementation more intuitive and much easier to debug.

```python
double_letter_cells = [
    #ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
    '...1.......1...',  # 1
    '...............',  # 2
    '......1.1......',  # 3
    '1......1......1',  # 4
    '...............',  # 5
    '...............',  # 6
    '..1...1.1...1..',  # 7
    '...1.......1...',  # 8
    '..1...1.1...1..',  # 9
    '...............',  # 10
    '...............',  # 11
    '1......1......1',  # 12
    '......1.1......',  # 12
    '...............',  # 14
    '...1.......1...',  # 15
]

def checkDoubleLetterCell(row, col):
    return double_letter_cells[row][col] == '1'
```

**Build some intermediate products:**

If you really need the stacked logic, you can produce some intermediate products which are then much easier to verify and understand.

```python
SCRABBLE_SIZE = 15
middle = int(SCRABBLE_SIZE / 2)

def checkDoubleLetterCell(row, col):
    one_off_middle_row = (row == middle - 1) or (row == middle + 1)
    one_off_middle_col = (col == middle - 1) or (col == middle + 1)
    outer_middle_row = (
        row == 0 or row == SCRABBLE_SIZE - 1 or row == middle)
    outer_middle_col = (
        col == 0 or col == SCRABBLE_SIZE - 1 or col == middle)

    middle_middle_row = row == middle + int(middle / 2) + 1 or \
                        row == middle - int(middle / 2) - 1
    middle_middle_col = col == middle + int(middle / 2) + 1 or \
                        col == middle - int(middle / 2) - 1

    middle_middle_plus_row = row == middle + int(middle / 2) + 2 or \
                             row == middle - int(middle / 2) - 2
    middle_middle_plus_col = col == middle + int(middle / 2) + 2 or \
                             col == middle - int(middle / 2) - 2

    return (
        one_off_middle_row and one_off_middle_col or
        outer_middle_row and middle_middle_col or
        outer_middle_col and middle_middle_row or
        one_off_middle_col and middle_middle_plus_row or
        one_off_middle_row and middle_middle_plus_col
    )
```

**Test Code:**

And for completeness, here is the code I used to test the above.

```python
for i in range(SCRABBLE_SIZE):
    for j in range(SCRABBLE_SIZE):
        assert (double_letter_cells[i][j] == '1') \
               == checkDoubleLetterCell(i, j)
```

Comment: The lookup table can also be trivially extended to the other kinds of special cells.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of the scrabble board as something that is immutable, I don't know why you need to have a function like this at all.

Why not build a matrix to represent the board and simply look at the element in the matrix which represents the column/row combination you are interested in checking to see if it has any special behavior (like double letter score).

For example if you built this out into a class (in this case within a supporting module), that might look something like:

```
export module ScrabbleBoard {
    export type Coordinate = [number, number];
    export const enum SquareTypes = {
        regular,
        doubleLetter,
        tripleLetter,
        doubleWord,
        tripleWord
    }

    export class Board {
        public static squareTypes: SquareTypes = SquareTypes;
        public static dimensions: [number, number] = [15,15];
        protected readonly tripleWordSquares: Coordinate[] = [
            [0,0],
            [0,7],
            [0,14],
            [7,0],
            [7,14],
            [14,0],
            [14,7],
            [14,14]
        ];
        protected readonly doubleLetterSquares: Coordinate[] = [
            [0,3],
            [0,11],
            ...
        ];
        // similar properties for other special squares

        protected squares: SquareTypes[][];
        protected specialSquareTypes: string[] = [];

        constructor() {
            this.initSquares();
            this.initSpecialSquareTypes();
            this.initSpecialSquares();
        }

        protected initSquares() {
            for(let i = 0; i < Board.dimensions[0]; i++) {
                for(let j = 0; i < Board.dimensions[1]; j++);
                    this.squares[i][j]: SquareTypes = Board.squareTypes.regular;
                }
            }
        }

        // get special square type string values from enum (those with values > 0)
        // for later use in apply special square setting    
        protected initSpecialSquareTypes() {
            for(let value in Board.squareTypes) {
                if(
                    typeof Board.squareTypes[value] === 'number'
                    && Board.squareTypes[value] > 0
                ) {
                    this.specialSquareTypes.push(value);
                }
            }
        }

        // iterate through all special square types to apply special square
        // type based on coordinates in [type]Squares arrays
        protected initSpecialSquares() {
            for (let squareType in this.specialSquareTypes) {
                 const squareArray = squareType + 'Squares';
                 for (let coord: Coordinate in this[squareArray]) {
                     this.square[coord[0]][coord[1]] = Board.squareTypes[squareType];
                 }  
            }
        }

        public getSquareType(coord: Coordinate): SquareTypes {
            return this.squares[coord[0]][coord[1]];
        }
    }
}

// usage
import ScrabbleBoard = ScrabbleBoard.Board;
import BoardCoord = ScrabbleBoard.Coordinate;
import SquareTypes = ScrabbleBoard.SquareTypes;
const board: ScrabbleBoard = new ScrabbleBoard();
const regularSquare: BoardCoord = [0,1];
const tripleWordSquare: BoardCoord = [0,0];
console.log(board.getSquareType(regularSquare) === SquareTypes.regular); // true
console.log(board.getSquareType(tripleWordSquare) === SquareTypes.tripleWord); // true
console.log(board.getSquareType(tripleWordSquare) === SquareTypes.regular); // false
```

Obviously, you could expand on such a class for other game play considerations, or provide more specific square type checking functions like `isDoubleLetterSquare()`.

Answer (score 2):

A scrabble board is symmetric, but your code doesn't exploit this. To make the code easier, you only need to check the *distances* from the center.

```
const dx = Math.abs(x - (size - 1) / 2);
const dy = Math.abs(y - (size - 1) / 2);

return dx === 1 && dy === 1 ||
    dx === …
```